# form not being printed, not showing in codeigniter, how can i make it show?

Tags: forms, codeigniter

Ive created a page where i need to send a form, nothing special, everything should be simple.. and might sound bad but it was working, now i tried to submit it and was no result, checking the printed code (u know, the code that is downloaded in the browser) i see my form is missing, i am trying to figure out whats wrong, but nothing, ichecked for unclosed tags but the problem continues, any idea how to solve this? anyone had the same problem? only the tags of form are not showing. thanks

my code:

```
echo form_open('form/form/do_upload');
echo form_fieldset('Login Form');
inputs here (they are visible);
echo form_submit('login', 'Login');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close();
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access `/form/form/do_upload` directly?

Comment: make sure you have loaded the helper $this->load->helper('form')

Comment: Hi, when i access to the form/do_upload directly it shows a message I set.. it works normal, but the problem is the forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are uploading something through a form,you have to give

```
echo form_open_multipart();
```

**form_open_multipart()**

> This function is absolutely identical to the form_open() tag above except that it adds a multipart attribute, which is necessary if you would like to use the form to **upload files** with.

Source: [form_helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: thanks, but i am not uploading files, i already tried with that one

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this, well, I had like 12 forms in my page, and one of them (i was calling it from someone's code) was not closed, it was causing everyone else was missing, i dont know why.

Thanks for the help!